# Load Google contacts into bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on spread-the-word feature for my app where users can invite their friends. now I would like to show a nice bootstrap modal and populate it with Google contacts (the modal body will show a nice spinner until contacts are fetched).

There are 2 scenarios that I need to handle:

1 - user is redirected to Google for authentication and returned back to my app

2 - user has already granted permissions and now I need to load his contacts via ajax into the modal body.

I would like to have a simple solution that will answer both cases.

My question:
How to tackle the first scenario where the user is redirected to Google? single ajax call is not enough.

How would you tackle this?

Thanks!